# laravel validation rule for only letters

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am trying to add a validation rule to only accept letters. I am using the `regex` rule but its still not working. Here is my code below:

```
    /**
     * Validate request/input 
     **/
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u|max:255|unique:users,name,'.$user->id,
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
    ]);
```

Whenever I enter a name like `Foo Foo`, it is still succesful in signing up.

Any idea what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: Try `'name' => array('required','regex:/^[\p{L}\s-]+$/u', 'max:255', 'unique:users,name,'.$user->id),`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didnt work.

Comment: And if you remove the `/u`? Just use `'regex:/^[\p{L}\s-]+$/'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didnt work....

Comment: it's working fine thank you so much  @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your regex fails I think, I tried it on [Regexr](http://regexr.com) and couldn't get it to function, try this:

```
'name' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|max:255|unique:users,name,'.$user->id,
```

Let me know how you get on.

Here's the regex only: ^[a-zA-Z]+$

Comment: Interesting, I've just noticed you concatinate: $user->id, onto the end of this, why are you doing this may I ask as Regexr shows this regex as working :/

Comment: i was working in the wrong view / controller lmfaoooo, this worked.

Comment: ^.^ It happens. Nice catch though :p

Comment: Note: literally only supports alphabetic strings, no spaces allowed. "Börje Henriksson" will cause validation fail for example.

Answer (score 41):

According to [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-alpha) you can use :

- `alpha` for entirely alphabetic characters
- `alpha_dash` for alpha-numeric characters, as well as dashes and underscores and finally
- `alpha_num` for entirely alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: Note: not UTF-8 supported rules

Comment: @PatricNox you can make your own helper, search it I've answered in Github, you just need to know your alphabet

Comment: is it possible to use `alpha_dash` and allow white spaces as well?

Comment: @JudgeJules `alpha_dash` can only contain letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores.